# lxml iterparse mising child nodes

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml iterparse to read huge xml files. For a given mainElement, I check the child elements and process each child. But I notice that, on checking the children within an element, the parser is actually missing some child nodes sometimes. I even printed the length of each element, which should be a constant number for a given element tag, but it is sometimes smaller than it should be. And surprisingly, this happens usually during the 5th block (one block=> mainElement occurance). Is there a reason why the parser should miss the child nodes? Any clues?

Sample code-

```
from lxml import etree  
def parseXml(context,attribList,elemList,mainElement):      
   for event, element in context: 
       if element.tag == mainElement and event=='start':
            for child in element:
               if child.tag in elemList:
                   print len(child) #for a given child,the len should be constant
                   #do things   
       elif event=='end':
         element.clear()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the context, be sure to set the parameter `events` to `('end',)` rather than `('start',)`. Otherwise, you can get the very behavior you are describing.

```
context=etree.iterparse(filehandle, events=('end',), tag=mainElement)
```

---

I think the problem is that lxml is processing the XML in one thread while running `parseXml` in another, so you can reach a `start` element in `parseXml` before lxml is done parsing to the corresponding `end` element. So when you loop through the element's children, you only get a partial result.

---

By the way, [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/) gives a nice way to organize this, designed for processing very large XML:

```
def fast_iter(context, func, *args, **kwargs):
    # http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
    # Author: Liza Daly
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def parseXml(element,attribList,elemList): 
    for child in element:
       if child.tag in elemList:
           print len(child) #for a given child,the len should be constant
           #do things   

context=etree.iterparse(filehandle, events=('end',), tag=mainElement)   
fast_iter(context, parseXml, attribList, elemList)
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu for your response. I am using the events=('start','end') and proessing the elements in the 'start' event (edited my code above). And I think what you said is exactly what is happening. When processing on start event, the child nodes are still not read. I quickly updated my code to process things on end event instead and it seems to work. I am still testing though. Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: This doesn't seem to retrieve all the children in the element. It only returns the last child in the element. Reasoning?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was missing child-element data as I was parsing on `start`. Minor change to parse on `end` fixed my issue.